# Can't find the file with vim plugin Ctrlp

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

There is a file called `login.js` located in `~/website/blog/views/login.js`, I used the command `:Ctrlp ~/website/blog`, then typed in `login.js` to search this file, but ctrlp couldn't find it. The best match was `index.js`, which was nothing to do with it. Then I tried to search `/login.js` with the same command, this time it worked. Why? Can I do something to make `login.js` work too?

P.S. I tried to set

```
let g:ctrlp_max_depth = 10000
let g:ctrlp_max_files = 10000
```

didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing Ctrlp? Hit F5 while Ctrlp is open, and it should start looking for more files.

Comment: @WanderNauta didn't work, either.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) instead of [kien/ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) solved this problem.